# Azure Function on AKS with KEDA always stops

Tags: java, docker, azure-functions, azure-aks, azure-eventhub

I wrote a sample Azure Function in Java which gets triggered by eventhub messages. This function works fine when deployed in FunctionApp but when I containerized it and deployed it with KEDA I am seeing below error message all the time and function does not process any message.

```
      Worker process started and initialized.
info: Host.General[337]
      Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '00000000000000000000000001DD233B'.
info: Host.Startup[413]
      Host started (7675ms)
info: Host.Startup[0]
      Job host started
info: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.DrainModeManager[0]
      DrainMode mode enabled
info: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.DrainModeManager[0]
      Calling StopAsync on the registered listeners
info: Host.Startup[0]
      Stopping the listener 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.EventHubs.Listeners.EventHubListener' for function 'MyFirstAKSFunction'
info: Host.Startup[0]
      Stopped the listener 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.EventHubs.Listeners.EventHubListener' for function 'MyFirstAKSFunction'
info: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.DrainModeManager[0]
      Call to StopAsync complete, registered listeners are now stopped
```

Docker file:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/java:4-java17

COPY ./build ./package
RUN mkdir -p /home/site/wwwroot && \
    cd /package/azure-functions/ && \
    cd $(ls -d */|head -n 1) && \
    cp -a . /home/site/wwwroot

ENV AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/home/site/wwwroot \
    AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true
```

The function starts and immediately starts shutting down.

Comment: Kindly check if these help- https://medium.com/c-sharp-progarmming/scale-azure-functions-app-on-kubernetes-using-keda-751d0eced965
https://linkedin.com/pulse/azure-functions-kubernetes-keda-orestis-meikopoulos/
https://microsoft.github.io/AzureTipsAndTricks/blog/tip278.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated the dockerfile and that fixed the issue. New dockerfile is below

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/java:4-java17

COPY ./build ./package

RUN mkdir -p /home/site/wwwroot && \
    cd /package/azure-functions/ && \
    cd $(ls -d */|head -n 1) && \
    cp -a . /home/site/wwwroot && \
    groupadd appuser -g 2000 && \
    useradd -r -M -s /sbin/nologin -g appuser -c appuser appuser -u 1000 && \
    mkdir -p /home/appuser/.local && \
    chown -R appuser:appuser /azure-functions-host && \
    chown -R appuser:appuser /home/appuser/.local

ENV AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/home/site/wwwroot \
    AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true \
    ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:8080 \
    FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME=java \
    JAVA_OPTS="--add-opens=java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/jdk.internal.misc=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED"

# Switch to the user
USER appuser

# Expose the port
EXPOSE 8080
```